# Using session and cookies for persistent data

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I'm about to tackle a 'shopping cart' of sorts in PHP, but as I'm still new to all this, I wanted to find out the best approach from people that know better.

I want items that are added to the basket to be available for several days, should the user not log in or checkout.  I've been using zavvi.com as an example so I can try to replicate how they do it.

I know that session data is only available whilst the browser is open, and is deleted from the server's memory when the browser is closed.  I also understand that cookies are saved to the client for more persistent data, with a defined expiry.

However, using Zavvi as an example, I can't understand how the cookie does its thing. There is a cookie called 'ElysiumBasketzavvi_V6' that presumably stores the contents of the basket. But the content (e.g. MjI1MzM3NjI4) of the cookie looks like some sort of encryption?

I'd be very grateful if someone could give me a few points regarding the order of events, when to use the session ID and how to store and retrieve basket contents so that it works like Zavvi, which I'm assuming is how it should be done.

Comment: The cookie has just that code? Looks like some identifier, maybe they save the cart session in the DB and use that code as a lookup. I'd do like this, since cookies have a limited amount of space and can be erased easily

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. The data is stored in the database and it's referenced via a hash. At least while the user is not logged-in...once he logs in, this data entry can be linked to the user's account and thus be available via the session.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So if the user adds something to the basket, its written to the database but then the user never goes back to the site, how is the database cleaned up of old basket content?

Comment: Also, if the shopping basket cookie contains an identifer, why do they store the session ID in another cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few incorrect assumptions.

> I know that session data is only available whilst the browser is open,
>   and is deleted from the server's memory when the browser is closed

Wrong. You can configure the session handler to use files, database or implement your own driver.

Cookies can only sore a small amount of data by design. Application data, other than identifiers, flags or small data chunks and likes should not be stored in them.

To be able to return to a session at any time, you need to configure both server and client side properly. The best is to use DB for session storage for persistency, make sure session GC is configured not to collect inactive sessions and set a long enough expiry time on the session cookie.

But since you want the user to be able to return to their shopping basket, this does not necessarily have to be achieved via long session timeout. Instead, you can just persist the content of the user's basket in database, so when they log in the next time, the basket contents is still there.

Comment: Thanks @Marcell. So it looks like storing sessions in a table is the best approach.  This tutorial looks good http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

Comment: Not really. What I tried to suggest, is that simply saving the basket content to database and redisplaying to users could do the job. On the other hand, if you want to keep the basket content for not registered, not logged in guests, then indeed, the session db storage could be a good solution.